# Unable to install GDAL with Anaconda + Pytorch (2020)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, gdal, anaconda3

I want to install GDAL in an Anaconda environment along with Pytorch. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

I tried 3 versions of Anaconda (2019.03, 2019.07, 2020.11).

I followed the advice mentioned in previous questions - like ensuring that channel priority has been set to strict and using `conda-forge` channel explicitly (`conda install gdal -c conda-forge`).

I tried installing an earlier version of python (python 3.5, 3.6 etc) in the environment and then installing anaconda and then installing gdal.

Sometimes I also tried fresh Anaconda installations and didn't work.

In all of the permutations I tried, I had one of the following problems:

1. Stuck at "Solving" (2+ hours)
2. Some kind of version conflict
3. Installation works but I am unable to import the gdal package in scripts. For eg I got this error in a couple of cases:

> ImportError: libcharset.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory"

I have been stuck with this for the past 3 days and will be really grateful if I could get some pointers on how to install Anaconda + GDAL + Pytorch.

Answer (score 1):

I found out from [another post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/74060) that the following commands might help:

`sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev` 
`export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal` 
`export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal`

Also, It turns out that setting `channel_priority` to `strict` resulted in version conflicts (`conda config --set channel_priority false`).

Answer (score 0):

You can install an old version:

```
conda create -n gdal_env python=3.6 gdal
```